How to test send Firebase silent push notifications?
I don't have experience using Firebase, and I'm trying to test send a silent push notification through FCM to an Android app I'm developing. It seems I can only send regular notifications from the Firebase admin (which I've been able to do), but not the silent ones I'm trying to test.
I'm trying to use cURL to hit FCM's HTTP V1 API this way:
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <OAuth id>" -X POST -d '{ "data":{ "foo":"1", "bar":"2" }, "to":"<token>", "android":{ "priority":"high" }}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project name}/messages:send

token: FCM registration token that I get through the android app on my test device, seems to be correct.
OAuth id: "OAuth 2 Client ID" that I got from https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project={project name}&supportedpurview=project, which I'm not sure is the one I should use.


I'm getting UNAUTHENTICATED as a response.
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}

Is there a straight-forward way to test silent push notifications, or is it supposed to be this convoluted? If so, what am I missing here?

I'm not sure what's convoluted about it, but the way to test it is to call the documented API. Authorization for that is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

Sorry, @FrankvanPuffelen, when I said it was convoluted I should've mentioned the docs you pointed me to: it seems that the only way to test it is through a server. looptheloop88's OAuth's playground is the kind of thing I was looking for.

Based on the response itself, the request to send FCM notification contains an invalid OAuth 2.0 access token. To generate a valid OAuth 2.0 access token, kindly follow the instructions given in this documentation.
For testing purposes, you can try to generate an OAuth 2.0 access token using the options below:

Using Google Developers OAuth 2.0 Playground

Select https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging as the scope
Click Authorize APIs
Once Authorization code is generated, exchange it to access token
Copy the access token and use it in the request


Using Firebase Cloud Messaging Node.js Quickstart Project

Install Firebase Admin SDK and Node.js
Download the quickstart project and follow the guide in README.md file
Update index.js and log the access token
Copy the access token and use it in the request



Note that the usual prefix of access token is ya29.

Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA


Google Developers OAuth 2.0 Playground is the kind of thing I was looking for as a way to test silent pushes without having to go through a server. Thank you.
